# Can we bring the <!-​- version --> syntax to Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, markdown, language-versions

Recently, Documentation introduced the `<!-- version -->` syntax for wrapping an example's code and text. This is [very useful](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/475/conditionals/1560/optional-binding-and-where-clauses#t=201608251815377898626) for languages like [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_%28Apple_programming_language%29) which drop and add a lot between versions.

We've dealt with this on Stack Overflow by [using headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29741007/3939277), but it would be very nice to have such an encompassing block to make it clear which parts are for which versions, or which parts can be shared across versions.

---

#### Examples:

In these, the fundamental answer doesn't change, but the edit history shows that the syntax had been tweaked/updated for the evolving language:

- [Swift equivalent of Array.componentsJoinedByString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727050/swift-equivalent-of-array-componentsjoinedbystring/24727167#24727167)
- [Any way to replace characters on Swift String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200888/any-way-to-replace-characters-on-swift-string/24201206#24201206)
- [How do I get a reference to the app delegate in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046164/how-do-i-get-a-reference-to-the-app-delegate-in-swift/24046979#24046979)
- [swift for loop: for index, element in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028421/swift-for-loop-for-index-element-in-array/24028458#24028458)
- [Get nth character of a string in Swift programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language/24178591#24178591)
- [How do I shuffle an array in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026510/how-do-i-shuffle-an-array-in-swift/24029847#24029847)
- [How to use substringToIndex in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904738/how-to-use-substringtoindex-in-swift)
- [Swift: How to expand a tilde in a path String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38173050/swift-how-to-expand-a-tilde-in-a-path-string)

Note also that I just found these with a cursory search, only within Swift since that's what I encounter in my day-to-day, and there are hundreds of other examples around the site.

Comment: Well, it is a nice excuse to not have to maintain your answers.  Can't say I'm looking forward to the inevitable "Does this work in 1.2.34.5 too?" comments however.

Comment: This feature will just encourage answers that have lots of interrupted reading flow because you constantly need to switch between versions. It works for docs because docs is essentially a big reference, but answers are primarily written in coherent sentences to answer the actual question. If the version requirements are not clear from the question, then one should assume whatever is current. If you want to make special version-specific notes, you can do so by just writing it down like that.

Comment: @poke A large number of answers already exist which have multiple specific version solutions listed within them, but are not formatted consistently across answers (sometimes even within the same one). Introducing this will introduce and encourage consistent formatting which will make such answers more easily-readable.

Comment: No, introducing this will only add another feature that people either won’t use or will use incorrectly (just look at snippets). Just because a feature is there, that doesn’t mean that everything suddenly becomes consistent and everything. And answers are not consistent by design because they are written by different people and targeted to different questions. I can see where you are coming from, but this won’t work for Q/A; it’s a different concept to docs.

Comment: @poke it's true that the existence of a feature does not mean immediate, widespread, nor proper adoption. However, that is and always has been a big reason why others can edit answers. This neither helps nor hurts feature misuse/disuse.

Answer (score 9):

I think this feature would be *very* useful for JavaScript answers. When people ask JavaScript questions they seldom explicitly specify which version they're using. See my meta question: [Are answers using latest, not widely supported ECMAScript features discouraged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332817/3853934) The consensus is that if someone writes an answer using latest ES features, they should explicitly state which version they're using. As a result in a half of my answers I write something like that:

> This answer uses latest ECMAScript features, which are not supported by older browsers. If you want this answer to work in all environments, you should use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to compile your code.

It would be great if I could use the `<!-- version -->` syntax to mark my answers (or parts of them) as using ES 6+.

Examples of my answers which would benefit from this feature:

- [RGB to Hex and Hex to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb/39077686#39077686)
- [Cleaning up some ridiculous JavaScript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053395/cleaning-up-some-ridiculous-js-code/39053564#39053564)
- [How to sum the values of a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449295/how-to-sum-the-values-of-a-javascript-object/39046365#39046365)
- [Re-associating an object with its class after deserialization in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922990/re-associating-an-object-with-its-class-after-deserialization-in-node-js/38923458#38923458)
- [Check if a string contains any element of an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428338/check-if-a-string-contains-any-element-of-an-array-in-javascript/37434514#37434514)
- [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects/35398031#35398031)
- [Get JavaScript object from array of objects by value or property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-or-property/35397839#35397839)

Comment: I'd like to see a quick HTML mockup of how it'd look with one of those boxes in there.  But that's more for bonus points, really.

Comment: I don’t see how your answers would benefit from that feature. From how I see it, you would mostly put your whole answers into a single versioned block… And I personally think that “use babel” disclaimer at the end is unneeded noise. Just say it’s ES2015 and be done with it. If people want a non-ES2015 solution, there surely are enough other answers to choose from. Answers in Q/A don’t strive for completeness, it’s fine to have multiple answers complementing each other by giving various possible solutions.

Comment: To add to @poke's case (and is touched on in my answer), the likelihood that this would be valid would be in the case of an answer that's long-lived through a community wiki, or the answerer is maintaining it.  In those scenarios, why would adding a new answer with the alternative approach be unacceptable?

Comment: @Makoto In theory people could write multiple answers, but people generally don't do that because of the scary popup that happens when you try to do that, telling you to instead improve the current answer.

Comment: @4castle:  If you're *sure* you want to create a new answer, then it's fine.  In effect you're still writing two answers if you're writing one solution for two different versions.  I'm not sure I would understand the apprehension from writing a new question.

Comment: @Makoto In many cases, versioning differences don't merit a separate answer. Since answers are supposed to be self-contained, you would have to re-explain the context for the answer, just to show the different syntax for an answer that is basically the same.

Comment: @4castle:  [I fundamentally disagree.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31422025/1079354)  There are answers in which adding an answer for a different version is perfectly fine.  Ultimately it depends on how nitpicky you wanted to get with adding another question in a different version, but I'm still not convinced that what you're describing would be an issue.

Comment: @Makato Often, editing an answer with hundreds of upvotes will gain its good content more attention than adding a better one below, especially if the edit doesn't fundamentally change the approach that was described in the original answer.

Comment: @BenLeggiero Editing a highly upvoted answer to completely change its content by adding additional *alternative* solutions seems to be a bad idea since that does not reflect at all the content the votes supported.

Comment: @poke no, I mean like these: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24201206/revisions#spacer-000d7aeb-48af-44a1-85cb-9960f0d082ae) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24046979/revisions#spacer-4d5d56f5-a2ae-409a-b742-2a8531230f8b) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24028458/revisions) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24178591/revisions) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24029847/revisions#spacer-24ad5cf9-9eba-4416-8587-087387efda80) Where the abswer's content doesn't completely change, but is adjusted for the language's evolving syntax, but otherwise stays the same.

Comment: answers should only provide code for the version tagged in the question, if there is no version tag, then clarification should be sought or a new answer for every version should be posted

Answer (score 6):

I hate to metaphorically answer a question with a question, but...

What use would we get out of these tags that adding a more up-to-date answer wouldn't provide?

To describe the scenario, we have a lot of answers from older versions of languages who have had their approaches revised, may be deprecated, or have had methods explicitly *removed*.  What worked in the past may not have been viable and the necessity of showing the different version is very, very obvious.

However, the way we've done this has been to add an answer with the newer approach taken on.  This way, the old answer can still live on, and is now detached from the new information.

Unless the answer is a Community Wiki, I'm not so sure that I see much value in bringing this feature over.  Don't get me wrong, it's an awesome feature, but Documentation is fundamentally different in its participation and information dissemination model than Q&A, and I'm not so sure this particular piece could fit in with Q&A.

(Not to mention the amount of curating we'd have to do for the versions.  Adding them freeform would spark more discussions.)

Comment: What if you wanted to use that feature in your own answer, to provide solutions in different versions of the language?

Comment: @Gothdo "If you have version <x use white magic, for anything else use the black one"

Comment: What about adding answer tags in contrast to question tags? E.g. a question could be tagged [tag:python] and an answer could be tagged [tag:python2], [tag:python3], both, or just [tag:python].

Comment: @Braiam The `<!-- version -->` syntax is IMO much more readable.

Comment: @Gothdo what? In what way a html comment is more readable than a properly structured english sentence?

Comment: @Gothdo:  When I've answered Java 7 questions, I've also included a proviso that indicated that there was a Java 8 variation that could be better.  I never had the pain point of needing to use a version marker analogous to Documentation's to ensure that the reader clearly understood that this applied only to Java 8 and above.  That said, I'm amenable to seeing a question that might need this; do you have an example of one that would strongly benefit?

Comment: @Braiam I meant the rendered output, not markdown.

Comment: @Makoto In JavaScript questions, OP very rarely states which version they are using, so if want to write an answer using the newest version, you have to explain that. See [my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333205/3853934).

Comment: In addition to clarifying and looking good, this gives a standardized, guaranteed way to specify a version disparity, whereas now it's sometimes a heading, sometimes bold, sometimes just a mishmash of paragraphs. Also, this leads the way for better parsing.

Comment: @BenLeggiero I don’t know about you, but I want people to *read* my answers instead of quickly scanning them for the correct code excerpt to copy/paste to fix their problem. I don’t want people to focus on versioned code blocks only.

Comment: @poke Adding versioning tags won't stop people from not reading your answers. This isn't designed to address that problem.

Comment: @4castle:  How does it *help*, though?  If you've got two answers to the same question, I don't see the harm in creating two separate answers.

Comment: @Gothdo:  To your point of the OP not stating what  version they're using, that does cause me a bit of pause; if a user decides to copy your code *carte blanche* and then comes back and asks you why it doesn't work with their environment, we now have a much **bigger** problem to solve; one I don't think we're in the business of solving.

Answer (score 4):

#### The road to hell is paved with good intentions:

I think the intent is good, but the implementation would have to be different.

Questions already have version tags ( [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [java-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-6), [java-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-7), [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8), [java-9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-9) and various synonyms ) and answers to those questions should be for those versions.

If you need code for a different version, then that is legitimately a new question and should be tagged as such and the answers should only address that new version.

#### Consequences:

I don't think this is a good idea because much like code comments that get out of sync with edits, it just adds more likely hood of things getting out of sync and more disparate things to be maintained.

Do you really want someone coming along and editing and adding version `1.0.8`, `1.1.2`, `J++`, `1.2`, `1.3`, `1.4`, `1.5`, `1.6`, `6`, `7`, `8` and `9` version code answers to every [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) answer just because? That is not a good scenario, especially when the edits are just wrong, do you want to get flooded with *suggested edit* notifications that have been *approved* by a bunch of no-nothings and have to roll them all back every day you log into SO? And you will be accumulating down votes from all the bad edits until they are rolled back.

#### Aside:

I participated in the non-public docs beta, I created some content. After docs went public, every one of my contributions was vandalized with edits that made the examples just plain wrong because the editors were editing to match their preferred code style without understanding that things like `final` variables are not *stylistic* and removing the `final` semantic breaks the examples.

Many of these edits were to add other language version of code, where the example title specifically mentioned a single language version for a reason.

After *fixing/rolling back* things multiple times repeatedly and the reasons to stop approving the edits were ignored, I just quit, my contributions should reflect my knowledge, docs does not do that.

I predict that if this is not addressed where good content is edited into just incorrect content over and over again, that docs is going to become the next w3schools reputation wise.

Comment: Questions might have such tags, but Google does not respect that. If I search "How to `x` in `language`", SO is likely to be in the top 3, and likely that question is years old. If there's a new version of that question in a new language, there's no link to it and it probably didn't show up in that original search.

Comment: Does not stop you from filtering on the tags on the site.

Comment: As true as that is, my intuition is that most people just use Google search instead